# Prove that $(uv)^R = v^Ru^R$

Tags: formal-languages, strings

> The reverse of a string, introduced informally above, can be defined more precisely by the recursive rules $$a^R=a,$$ $$(wa)^R=aw^R,$$ for all $a \in \Sigma$, $w \in \Sigma^*$. Use this to prove that $$(uv)^R = v^Ru^R,$$ for all $u, v \in \Sigma^+$.

This is exercise 3 (page 28) from "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata" by Peter Linz. I am not used to this type of exercise, so I would like some help to get the hang of it.

My attempt: Suppose $u = u_1...u_n$ and $v = v_1...v_n$. So, $$(uv)^R = (u_1...u_nv_1...v_{n-1}v_n)^R = v_n(u_1...u_nv_1...v_{n-1})^R \implies (uv)^R = v^Ru^R.$$

Is it correct? If not, any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). In this case, use $|u|$ for the induction. ($|uv|$ is also possible, of course, but you'll probably find that there are fewer cases with $|u|$. But trying both is maybe a good learning exercise.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on your standard of proof. Let's try to be very strict.

First of all, let us define words. In contrast to Peter Linz, we will not be afraid of the empty string. The set of words $\Sigma^*$ satisfies the following:

- If $w \in \Sigma^*$ then either $w = \epsilon$ or $w = x\sigma$, where $x \in \Sigma^*$ and $\sigma \in \Sigma$.
- $\epsilon \neq x\sigma$ for every $x \in \Sigma^*$ and $\sigma \in \Sigma$.
- $x\sigma = y\tau$ iff $x=y$ and $\sigma=\tau$.
- Define an *inductive subset* of $\Sigma^*$ to be a subset $S \subseteq \Sigma^*$ such that (i) $\epsilon \in S$ and (ii) if $x \in S$ then $x\sigma \in S$ for all $\sigma \in \Sigma$.

  - $\Sigma^*$ is an inductive subset.
  - If $S$ is an inductive subset then $S = \Sigma^*$.

Now we can define concatenation of words inductively:

- $w.\epsilon = w$.
- $w.(x\sigma) = (w.x)\sigma$.

Finally, we define reversal:

- $\epsilon^R = \epsilon$.
- $(x\sigma)^R = \sigma.x^R$, where $\sigma$ is syntactic sugar for $\epsilon \sigma$ (which we know to be in $\Sigma^*$ since it is an inductive subset).

We need several lemmas.

**Lemma 1.** For all $x \in \Sigma^*$, we have $\epsilon.x = x$.

**Proof.** Let $S = \{ x \in \Sigma^* : \epsilon.x = x \}$. We will show that $S$ is an inductive subset, and so $S = \Sigma^*$, that is, $\epsilon.x = x$ for all $x \in \Sigma^*$.

If $x = \epsilon$ then $\epsilon.\epsilon = \epsilon$. If $x = y\sigma$, where $y \in S$, then $\epsilon.x = \epsilon.y\sigma = (\epsilon.y)\sigma = y\sigma = x$, using $y \in S$. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** For all $x,y,z \in \Sigma^*$, $x.(y.z) = (x.y).z$.

**Proof.** Fix $x,y \in \Sigma^*$, and let $S = \{ z \in \Sigma^* : x.(y.z) = (x.y).z \}$. We will show that $S$ is an inductive subset, and so $S = \Sigma^*$.

If $z = \epsilon$ then $x.(y.z) = x.y = (x.y).z$.

Now suppose that $z = w\sigma$, where $w \in S$. Then
$$
x.(y.z) = x.(y.w\sigma) = x.((y.w)\sigma) = (x.(y.w))\sigma = ((x.y).w)\sigma = (x.y).(w\sigma) = (x.y).z,
$$
using $z \in S$. $\square$

Now we are ready to prove your claim.
Fix $x \in \Sigma^*$, and let $S  = \{ y \in \Sigma^* : (x.y)^R = y^R.x^R \}$. We will show that $S$ is an inductive subset, and so $S = \Sigma^*$, that is, $(x.y)^R = y^R.x^R$ for all $y \in \Sigma^*$.

If $y = \epsilon$ then
$$ (x.y)^R = x^R = \epsilon.x^R = \epsilon^R.x^R, $$
using Lemma 1.

If $y = z\sigma$, where $z \in S$, then
$$ (x.y)^R = (x.(z\sigma))^R = ((x.z)\sigma)^R = (\epsilon\sigma)^R. (x.z)^R. $$
Let us notice that $(\epsilon\sigma)^R = \epsilon\sigma.\epsilon^R = \epsilon\sigma.\epsilon = \epsilon\sigma$. Also, since $z \in S$, $(x.z)^R = z^R.x^R$. Therefore
$$ (x.y)^R = (\epsilon\sigma).(z^R.x^R) = ((\epsilon\sigma).z^R).x^R = (z\sigma)^R .x^R = y^R.x^R.$$
using Lemma 2. $\square$

---

While I tried to be rather strict, a completely formal proof will be even stricter: it will justify every single step, referring to a definition, a lemma, or a logical axiom. However, the proof above should be easy to convert to something that proof assistants can grok.

---

In practice, you can prove your claim as follows. Let $x = \sigma_1 \ldots \sigma_n$ and $y = \tau_1 \ldots \tau_m$. Then
$$
(xy)^R = (\sigma_1 \ldots \sigma_n \tau_1 \ldots \tau_m)^R = \tau_m \ldots \tau_1 \sigma_n \ldots \sigma_1 = (\tau_m \ldots \tau_1) (\sigma_n \ldots \sigma_1) = y^R x^R.
$$
At a more advanced stage, this proof can be summarized by "obvious".

Comment: +1, because of all the details, but mostly because of your last line.

Comment: +1. I'm on my way to completing all of the book exercises, and there are just way too many obvious ones to prove.